# How to associate language to file without extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Is it achievable? If so what is the syntax in below:

```
"files.associations": {}
```

Comment: Dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656415/associate-extensionless-files-to-bash/