# Associate extensionless files to Bash

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Bash scripts do not have any extensions nor shebang line. How can I avoid having to select the syntax highlighter when I open every file for this project?

Comment: Why not just give them a shebang or .sh extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `files.associations` setting allows matching against arbitrary glob patterns, not just file extensions. For instance, for a Bash script named `start`, you could have the following in your workspace's `settings.json`:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "start": "shellscript"
}
```

You can also have a comma-separated list of file names between `{}`:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "{start,stop}": "shellscript"
}
```